# How to omit the "." directory when creating a tar from directory?

Tags: shell, archiving, tar

To create a backup of entire directory I do:

```
tar -cPzf /home/misha/path/to/tar/tar_name.tar.gz 
    -C /home/misha/path/to/directory/to/backup .
```

In the resulting `tar_name.tar.gz` beside the files themselves I see also the `.` directory.

Is it possible not to create it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tar czf mybackup.tar.gz /home/misha/path/to/directory/to/backup
```

This command will compress the directory `/home/misha/path/to/directory/to/backup` into `mybackup.tar.gz` in your current directory.

Comment: I'm not interested in making the tar in the current directory. I would like it to be in `/home/misha/path/to/tar` (and I prefer not to `cd` to this directory, if possible).

Comment: Then do `tar cvf /home/misha/path/to/tar.tgz /home/misha/path/to/directory/to/backup`

Comment: Barry is right. Just add the full path and you can run the tar in any directory you like. +1 Baz :-)

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that the created tar contains all the directories, i.e. `home->misha->path->to->directory->to->backup`, rather than just the files themselves. How could I enforce not to create this directory structure ?

Comment: Ok. I understand what you want now. Use -C to chdir. For example: tar -czf myfile.tar.gz -C /mylocation myfile.txt -C /file2 file2.txt -C /other/dir afile.html

Comment: @slotishtype: You are getting closer to my original example :) The question is how to archive a whole directory rather than separate files (and not having the `.` directory in the resulted tar) ?

Comment: tar -czf /home/misha/path/to/tar/myfile.tar.gz -C /mylocation myfile.txt -C /file2 file2.txt -C /other/dir afile.html ... This can executed from any dir.

Comment: I've done my best. Good luck

Comment: @slotishtype: Again, I would like to archive a directory (see my original example).

Comment: @slotishtype let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/683/discussion-between-misha-moroshko-and-slotishtype)